# Combine and sum up array elements by first element

Tags: php

I have some code like this:

```
<?php
  function combineTypeValue($typeValueArray){
    //coding here ...
  }
  $typeValue=array("0x80","0x20","0x200","0x1000000");
  $typeValue=combineTypeValue($typeValue);
?>
```

After function combineTypeValue(), the elements in  array $typeValue I want to have:

`["0x80","0xa0","0x280","0x1000080","0x2a0","0x10000a0","0x1000280","0x10002A0"]`

1.The output array elements is sum up by the **first element**.

2.The element order is unimportant.

3.The function can handle different length of array.

What should I do?

Comment: I can't see the pattern. Why is there an `a` in some of them?

Comment: [0x80","0x20","0x200","0x1000000"]->[a,b,c,d]           
 ["0x80","0xa0","0x280","0x1000080","0x2a0","0x10000a0","0x1000280","0x10002A0"]=[a,a+b,a+c,a+d,a+b+c,a+b+d,a+c+d,a+b+c+d]